# Assigned(TStopWatch) gives E2008

Tags: delphi-10.1-berlin

```
if assigned(S3) then Log('TChunkManager.UpdateVertices Create VAO ms: ' + 
  S3.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString);
```

The problem is the assigned part, I tried with Log('aaa') and also Log works fine elsewhere. Why is S3 (TStopwatch) is uncompatible with assigned?

```
**[dcc64 Error] thChunkManager.pas(529): E2008 Incompatible types**
```

How can I check if S3 is created or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) is a [**record type**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Records_.28traditional.29), not a [**class type**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Class_Types).  An instance of a record can be created in stack memory of the calling thread.  An instance of a class type must be allocated dynamically in heap memory instead.   Only pointers can be passed to `Assigned()`.  A record instance on the stack doesn't count.

For what you are attempting, you probably want to use the [`TStopWatch.IsRunning`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch.IsRunning) property instead:

```
if S3.IsRunning then
  Log('TChunkManager.UpdateVertices Create VAO ms: ' + S3.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString);
```

Comment: Why doesn't the naming convention give any hint about this? Record types could be named with different prefix, like RStopWatch for example. Would save some trouble with faulty freeing and such if it was automatically obvious without having to know or to check each type.